# Difficulty using predict()

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, analysis, prediction

[Dataset](http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html)I am trying to predict the airline delays and I am facing difficulty when I am predicting the values on my test data. The output goes into an infinite loop and I am unable to understand why. Below is the reproducible code.

```
arrdelaymodel <- lm(ArrDelay ~ DepDelay + Distance + Distance*AirTime + HDAYS +DepTime*DepDelay)
summary(arrdelaymodel)

what.are.my.chances <- function(DepDelay, Distance,  AirTime, DepTime,  HDAYS){
new.values <- data.frame("DepDelay" = testing_data$DepDelay, "Distance" =    testing_data$Distance, "AirTime"=
                       testing_data$AirTime, "DepTime"= testing_data$DepTime,  "HDAYS"=testing_data$HDAYS)
output <- predict(arrdelaymodel, newdata = new.values)
return(output)
}

what.are.my.chances(DepDelay = 10, Distance = 200, AirTime = 100, DepTime = 1700, HDAYS= 7)
```

Comment: Your function is not using its parameters. Also, don't use `attach`; use the `data` parameter of `lm`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you make a mistake with subsetting the data. E.g. you call the function with `DepDelay' = 10`. So the function then tries to do the following: `testing_data$10`.

Just removing the 'testing_data$' part should solve the problem, i.e.:

`new.values <- data.frame("DepDelay" = DepDelay, .. )`

Good luck!

Comment: How would it know it has to check in the test data? The model is being run on training data. Il just say below?
    new.values <- data.frame("DepDelay" =Depdelay, ....data=testing_data)

Comment: Or just attach(testing_data) just before the prediction?

Comment: I assume that the values you provide to the function arguments are values from the testdata? If you have/make a dataframe containing the test data you could do the following:
`what.are.my.chances <- function(testdata){
new.values <- data.frame("DepDelay" = testdata[,'DepDelay'], "Distance" =    testdata[,'Distance'], "AirTime" =  testdata[,'AirTime'], "DepTime" = testdata[,'DepTime'],  "HDAYS" = testdata[,'HDAYS'])
output <- predict(arrdelaymodel, newdata = new.values)
return(output)
}

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes it does! :)